# ERR:-ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: hex to raw conversion error

Tags: java, oracle

i created wrapper function as below on java source

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION APPS.xxdecrptyBySyymetricKey (emp_f_name 
VARCHAR2,
  emp_l_name RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS LANGUAGE JAVA
  NAME 'XXBEL_EINVOICE_ENC.decrptyBySyymetricKey(java.lang.String, 
java.lang.byte[]) return java.lang.Sting';
```

---

```
public static String decrptyBySyymetricKey(String encryptedSek, byte[] appKey)
 {
  Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(appKey, "AES"); // converts bytes(32 byte random generated) to key
  try {
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); // encryption type = AES with padding PKCS5
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey); // initiate decryption type with the key
  BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
  byte[] encryptedSekBytes = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedSek); // decode the base64 encryptedSek to bytes
   byte[] decryptedSekBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedSekBytes); // decrypt the encryptedSek with the initialized cipher containing the key(Results in bytes)
  BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
  String decryptedSek = base64encoder.encode(decryptedSekBytes); // convert the decryptedSek(bytes) to Base64 StriNG
   return decryptedSek; // return results in base64 string
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
   return "Exception; "+e;
  }
}
```

ERR:-ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: hex to raw conversion error
OR
ORA-01465: invalid hex number

Comment: How are you calling this function? That's where the error is coming from.

Comment: Check the last row. You are returning `java.lang.Sting` instead of `java.lang.String`